# Visual Studio Intellisense with nullable enum parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Using Visual Studio 2022 with c#. Sample code:

```
    private void DoSomething(SomeEnum? val = SomeEnum.A)
    {
        // do something. 
    }
```

where enum is defined like:

```
public enum SomeEnum 
{
    A,
    B,        
}
```

Now, when calling `DoSomething`:

```
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething()
    }
```

The intellisense on the parameters in the call to `DoSomething`, shows: `SomeEnum? val = 0` :

[image]

I was hoping to see instead: `SomeEnum? val = SomeEnum.A`  , which would be more helpful.

e.g. if `DoSomething` was changed to make `val` not nullable:

```
    private void DoSomething(SomeEnum val = SomeEnum.A)
    {
        // do something. 
    }
```

then the intellisense would be:

[image]

Might there be any workarounds to make the intellisense show `SomeEnum? val = SomeEnum.A`   when val is nullable ?

Comment: Do you use resharper?

Comment: no. What do you see with resharper (if you use it) ?

Comment: I just googled for "intelisense nullable enum shows value" and found a bunch of similar complaints, and half are related to resharper.

Comment: According to [Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum), _By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int...The default value of an enumeration type E is the value produced by expression (E)0, even if zero doesn't have the corresponding enum member_

Comment: I use ReSharper and I see "SomeEnum? val = bad value". That is with the newly-released VS 17.4.2 and Re#er 2022.2.4.

Comment: This is a known bug https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39502

Comment: I'd imagine that no one considered that someone would make a parameter nullable and then provide an optional value that wasn't null. It doesn't make much sense to me either why one would make the parameter nullable and then provide an optional value that isn't null. The following makes sense (to me): `private void DoSomething(SomeEnum? val = null)`. This one, `private void DoSomething(SomeEnum? val = SomeEnum.A)` not so much.

Comment: One may notice that when typing `DoSomething(` the first value in the enum that isn't listed as an optional parameter value shows up. If one uses `private void DoSomething(SomeEnum? val = null)`, then `SomeEnum.A` shows  up within the parentheses. However, if one uses `private void DoSomething(SomeEnum? val = SomeEnum.A)`, then `SomeEnum.B` shows  up within the parentheses.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a setting to achieve this. Maybe you can report this on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest) and request a feature

Comment: @shingo - if you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.